# How to process large outputs from netmiko quickly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get a list of vpns from a device on our network. This list is very long and does not fully return without further input. Is there a way to quickly get the full list without looping and repeatedly sending an enter command through the ssh connection?

I tried to use send command but that times out since the trailing characters are <--- More ---> instead of what is expected. send_command_timing doesnt time out but only returns a small part of the whole list with the trailing <--- More ---> text showing that i didnt get everything. Currently I am having it go through  a loop repeatedly using send_command_timing to get the next line and then stripping the <--- More ---> string from the output. The problem is that this method is extremely slow and would not be usable in any realistic fashion.

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host': "example.host",
    'username': "user",
    'password': "pass",
}
trailingString = "<--- More --->"

connect = ConnectHandler(**device)

print("Connection complete")

connect.send_command("enable 3" + '\n', expect_string="Password:")
connect.send_command("pass" + '\n', expect_string="#")

output = connect.send_command_timing("sho vpn-sessiondb svc")

while trailingString in output:
    if(output.endswith(trailingString)):
        output = output[:-(len(trailingString) + 1)] # Added + 1 to remove the trailing newline
        output += connect.send_command_timing("\n")

print(output)
connect.disconnect()
```

I haven't been able to find a solution that will retrieve all of the output of the send_command_timing function quickly enough for it to be reasonable to use. I expect that there is a better/faster way to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the "cisco_ios" device type, but are connecting to a Cisco ASA (based on the "show vpn-sessiondb svc" command that you are sending)?

Netmiko should automatically disable output paging shortly after the SSH connection is completed. Consequenlty, you shouldn't be seeing the '<--- More --->' string in the output.

I suspect if you switch the Netmiko device type to "cisco_asa" that the output paging problem will go away.

Or worded differently, since you are using the "cisco_ios" device type the wrong command to disable output paging is being sent to the remote device. Once you switch to the right device type the proper command should be sent (i.e. Netmiko will automatically send that "terminal pager 0" command).

Comment: I swapped it to cisco_asa but i cant figure out how to have the default connection try enable 3 instead of just enable. So when I try to connect with cisco_asa the default enable behavior fails since the given password is for enable 3 not enable. How would i set up the ConnectHandler to setup enable 3 instead of enable?

Comment: Yes, that is going to be a bit of a problem...as ASA you can't disable paging without elevating privileges so it is baked into the ASA driver to just execute `enable` (not `enable 3`). You might be able to do this if the privilege escalation is tied to the username i.e. `login as` in which case you would set the enable secret to blank.

You might want to create a GitHub issue on the enable 3 problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to find a solution directly through netmiko but by changing some values on the device itself I was able to get the whole output. For the specific device I was connecting to it was using terminal pager 0 to remove the default line limit.

So by using connect.send_command("terminal pager 0") before running connect.send_command_timing("sho vpn-sessiondb svc") I was able to get the whole returned value.

```py
connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
#connect =  Netmiko(**device)
print("Connection complete")
connect.send_command("enable 3" + '\n', expect_string="Password:")
connect.send_command("enable3secret" + '\n', expect_string="#")
connect.send_command("terminal pager 0")
output = connect.send_command_timing("sho vpn-sessiondb svc")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking to see if you can run `terminal length 0`. If that doesn't work in your environment, there may be some other variant of this command that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I resolved this by setting the global_delay_factor to '2' for the target device session
[This link explains the concepts in greater detail](https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko-what-is-done.html)

```
    device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host': "x.x.x.x",
    'username': 'some_user',
    'password': 'some_pass',
    'global_delay_factor': 2
}
ssh = ConnectHandler(**device)
output = ssh.send_command("show running")
print(output)



enter code here
```